# Choice of design pattern - serial execution

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, jaxb

I have a simple design problem - I am looking for the best pattern to implement a simple functionality. Let's say, I am going to create an xml message in java. This message consists of many fields in different logic groups.

So, the first idea - create a class to set all fields. I can do it one method (which will be really long...) or split the method into multiple smaller (for each of the logical groups). However, I don't think it is a good approach, because the class will be really long and difficult to mantain.

The second idea is to create a functional interface and some implementations for different groups, for instance GroupXxxSetter, GroupYyySetter, etc. I can create and keep all instances in a list or a set and call the method defined inside the interface for each object stored inside the collection. It seems to be very similar to the 'Chain of responsibility' pattern. However, the idea of this pattern is different, so I am not sure if it is a good idea to use this pattern in my case.

Should I use the 'chain of responsibility' pattern here? Or, maybe there is something better?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use the 'chain of responsibility' pattern here?

Clearly, no. You don't have the notion of candidate responsible to respond to a request. All elements will do a processing.

> Or, maybe there is something better?

You have multiple possibilities.
Your context is not totally set. So it is hard to propose one rather than another.

I may propose you a implementation with the Builder pattern (Java Effective reference and not GOF).

For each logic group, you could have a specific class.
You would also have a composite class that is composed of logic group instances.

Instead of providing a public constructor or setters that prevent immutability and that can make rules validation cumbersome, you could use the Builder pattern  for each one logic group class and in the composite class, you could use the same kind of Builder pattern where you will build the final message from the previously created logic group instances.

You could so create the instances in this way :

```
OneLogicGroup oneLogicGroup = OneLogicGroup.builder().fieldXXX(...).fieldYYY(...).build();

AnotherLogicGroup anotherLogicGroup = AnotherLogicGroup .builder().fieldXXX(...).fieldYYY(...).build();

MyMessage myMessage = MyMessage.builder().oneLogicGroup(oneLogicGroup).anotherLogicGroup(anotherLogicGroup).build().
```

> I can create and keep all instances in a list or a set and call the
>   method defined inside the interface for each object stored inside the
>   collection.

It seems referring to a structural concern.
It is not directly related to the creation of the object. It is much related to how to share the created objects. 
The flyweight pattern addresses this need and may be used conjointly with the presented builder Pattern.